# Rename Variable with a string in saved in other variable in R

Tags: r, rename

I want to rename a matrix named "data" by string saved in a variable:

I used the following, but did not work:

```
library(plyr)
cityName = names(raster) 
rename(x= data, replace =("data" = cityName))
```

Comment: Please read carefully: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Formatting code as code is also advisable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `list2env`

```
string <- 'new_name'
list2env(setNames(list(data), string), .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this ?

```
string <- 'new_name'
assign(string, data)
#If not needed remove original data
rm(data)
```